# Calculate time and assign different backgrounds to textview according to time

Tags: android-listview, android, android-custom-view

Can anyone give me any recommendations as to how i should approach this properly?

Heres the problem, grab a beer first. My attempt to explain might require a cold one :)

- I have a ListView that is being populated via JSON that its being downloaded from a server.
- This listview has a pickup_time (String), I am calculating the difference in time between current time and pickup_time
- What I am trying to do is load either a green, yellow or red circle image to the assigned pickup_time according to the difference in time I have calculated by using a textView and using textView.setBackgroundColor. in the ListView.
- The ListView *WAS* working properly and displaying information correctly. I've recently only tried to add the green/yellow/red images to the corresponding pickup_time string and this is where its crashing and I need help.

Now for some Codes!

Heres is where I am populating the listView using an AsyncTask. If you notice, I have **parse_ready_at(JobsArray, i1);** This is where I am caluclating the time difference.

```
 public class Jobs extends ListActivity {



String NEW_JOB = " ";

Vibrator vib;

boolean reloadOnResume;


TextView assigned;

static ProjectDebug LOGCAT = new ProjectDebug();
ProgressDialogManager pDialog = new ProgressDialogManager();
static String JOB, ON_TIME_PERFORMANCE;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;


int PU_time_until_late;
int DEL_time_until_late;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
    getWindow().setLayout (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT /* width */ , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT /* height */); 

    vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    assigned = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.assigned);  


    RELOAD = true;
    Jobs.this.setTitle("My Jobs");

    reloadOnResume = false;

    VerifyDriverCredentials();



    // selecting single ListView item
    final ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long ide) {
            vib.vibrate(40);            

                // Starting new intent 
         try {  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class); 


                in.putExtra("jobInfo", JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString()); 
                in.putExtra(pays, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(customer_name, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(job, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(ready_at, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(due_by, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(customer_reference, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pieces, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(weight, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(signature_required, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(acknowledged, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_actual_datetime, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());


                // Pickup Info
                in.putExtra(pickup_name, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_addr1, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_city, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_state, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_to_see, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_room, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_phone, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_zip_postal, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(pickup_special_instr, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());


                // Deliver Info
                in.putExtra(deliver_name, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_addr1, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_city, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_state, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_zip_postal, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_to_see, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_room, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_special_instr, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());
                in.putExtra(deliver_phone, JOBS.getJSONObject(position).toString());


                startActivity(in); 

                Jobs.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout); 

                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            }

        });
    }







private void VerifyDriverCredentials() {
    if (jobs_assigned == 0){
        assigned.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        assigned.setText("You have no jobs assigned");
        GetWindowParameters();
    } 
    if (jobs_assigned > 0 && reloadOnResume == false) {
        assigned.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        new ParseJobs().execute();
    }

}







public class ParseJobs extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String DEL_late = "del_late";
    String PU_late = " pu_late";

    int i1 = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {     

        pDialog.showProgressDialog(Jobs.this, "Performing calculations", "Loading... Please Wait...");
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // looping through All Contacts
        try {   for (i1 = 0; i1 < JOBS.length(); i1++) {
                        JobsArray = JOBS.getJSONObject(i1);
                        JOB = JobsArray.getString(job);
                        ON_TIME_PERFORMANCE = JobsArray.getString(on_time_performance);             

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(job, JobsArray.getString(job));
                        map.put(pays, JobsArray.getString(pays));
                        map.put(ready_at, JobsArray.getString(ready_at));
                        map.put(due_by, JobsArray.getString(due_by));
                        map.put(new_job, JobsArray.getString(new_job));

                        //map.put(PU_late, Integer.toString(PU_time_until_late));
                        //map.put(DEL_late, Integer.toString(DEL_time_until_late));


                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        contactList.add(map); 
                    }           
                    } catch (JSONException e) { 

                    }

                                parse_ready_at(JobsArray, i1);


        return null;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if  (JOB != null) { assigned.setText("");                           } 
        else              { assigned.setText("You have no jobs assigned");  }





            GetWindowParameters();



            /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, ready_at, due_by, new_job, PU_late, DEL_late}, 
                                       new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.ready_at1, R.id.due_by1, R.id.newjob1, R.id.imageViewReadyAt, R.id.imageViewDueBy });


        TextView imageViewReadyAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewReadyAt);
        //Change color/answer/etc for textView_5

                if ( PU_time_until_late > 60) {                                     // if more than 60 minutes
                    imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification);
                }

                if ( PU_time_until_late < 60) {                                     //if less than 60
                    imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_light);
                }

                if ( PU_time_until_late < 30) {                                     // if less than 30
                    imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_light);
                }

                if ( PU_time_until_late < 1) {                                      // if less than 1 minutes
                    imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_light);
                }





            setListAdapter(adapter);        

            pDialog.dismissProgressDialog(Jobs.this);

    }
}



public void parse_ready_at(JSONObject JobsArray, int i1) {

                String parse_ready_at_ARRAY;
                String tracking_Number;         

        try {   for (i1 = 0; i1 < JOBS.length(); i1++) {
                    JobsArray = JOBS.getJSONObject(i1);

                    parse_ready_at_ARRAY = JobsArray.getString(ready_at);
                    tracking_Number = JobsArray.getString(job);


                //Example of ready_at String --> "ready_at": "07/25/2012 08:26:00 PM" we split time from date to get time only

  SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); // <--- Correct format to read "lastLatitudeUpdate"             
        try {   parserSDF.parse(parse_ready_at_ARRAY);      
                }


        catch   (ParseException e) {    LOGCAT.DEBUG("JOBS parse_ready_at", "Error parsing tracking number = " + tracking_Number + "      ready_at Array = " + parse_ready_at_ARRAY + " Error = " + e.toString());      } 



                    /* ################################################
                     * ####     DISSECTING READY_AT STRING ARRAY    ###
                     * ################################################
                     */
                String[] dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME = parse_ready_at_ARRAY.split(" ");       // Splitting space between 07/25/2012 and 08:26:00 and PM
                String   get_ready_at_DATE = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[0]);  // Set at 0 because we want date.  07-25-2012
                String   get_ready_at_TIME = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[1]);  // Set at 1 because we want time.  08:26:00
                String   get_ready_at_AMPM = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[2]);   // Set at 2 because we want AM PM. 


                    /* ########################################################
                     * ####     GETTING DATE FROM READY_AT STRING ARRAY     ###
                     * ########################################################
                     */             
                String[]  dissect_ready_at_DATE = get_ready_at_DATE.split("/");              // Splitting the / between 07 and 25 and 2012 from 07/25/2012
                     int  get_ready_at_MONTH = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[0]);    // Set at 0 because we want month. 07
                     int  get_ready_at_DAY =   Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[1]);    // Set at 1 because we want day.   25
                     int  get_ready_at_YEAR =  Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[2]);    // Set at 2 because we want yeay.  2012



                    /* ########################################################
                     * ####     GETTING TIME FROM READY_AT STRING ARRAY     ###
                     * ########################################################
                     */                 
                String[]  dissect_ready_at_TIME = get_ready_at_TIME.split(":");              // Splitting the : between 08 and   26 and 00 
                     int  get_ready_at_HOUR = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_TIME[0]);     // Set at 0 because we want hour.   08
                     int  get_ready_at_MINUTE = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_TIME[1]);   // Set at 1 because we want minute. 26 




                    /* ################################################################
                     * ####     CONVERT HOUR FROM READY_AT STRING TO MILITARY TIME  ###
                     * ################################################################
                     */ 
                     int convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = 0;                              // By default, ready_at String is in 12 hour format. we need to fix it so it is military time.

                     if (get_ready_at_AMPM.contentEquals("PM")) {                            // Checking to see if ready_at String has a PM at the end
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = get_ready_at_HOUR + 12;         // If it does, add 12 so we can get military time           
                     }

                     if (get_ready_at_HOUR == 12 & get_ready_at_AMPM.contentEquals("PM")  ) {// If hour is set at 12 PM, leave it at 12
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = 12;
                     }

                     if (get_ready_at_AMPM.matches("AM"))  {                                 // Do Nothing if its AM
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = get_ready_at_HOUR + 0;
                     }





                    /* ############################################################
                     * ####     GET THE CURRENT DATE/TIME FROM USERS DEVICE     ###
                     * ############################################################
                     */     
                     int    current_MONTH =  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);        // Get todays month
                     int    current_DAY =    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // Get todays date
                     int    current_YEAR =   Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);         // Get todays year

                     int    current_HOUR =   Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  // Get todays Hour in military format
                     int    current_MINUTE = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);       // Get todays minute         



                     int current_year_FIXUP = current_YEAR - 1900;          // example, this year is 2013, subtract 1900 you get 113 which is what Date parameter is requesting
                     int get_ready_at_year_FIXUP = get_ready_at_YEAR - 1900;

                     int get_ready_at_MONTH_FIXUP =  // * We dont need to fixup current_MONTH because java has already done so
                             get_ready_at_MONTH - 1; // <-- we subtract 1 because according to parameters, January starts at 0 and December is 11 


                     /* 
                      *  How to use Date(int, int, int) 
                      * 
                      * 
                      *     *Parameters*
                      *         - year  the year, 0 is 1900. 
                      *         - month  the month, 0 - 11. 
                      *         - day  the day of the month, 1 - 31 
                      */

                     Date ready_at_time = new Date(get_ready_at_year_FIXUP, get_ready_at_MONTH_FIXUP, get_ready_at_DAY); // (2010, June, 20th) = (110, 5, 20) June is 5  instead of 6 because we start 
                     Date current_time = new Date(current_year_FIXUP, current_MONTH, current_DAY);                       // January at 0 in Java. As for days, it starts at 1 like normal.


                     int days_between = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(current_time), new DateTime(ready_at_time)).getDays();    // Get the difference in days of current date and ready_at date

                     int minutes_difference_in_days_between = days_between * 1440;  // 1440 minutes = 1 day. multiply with the date difference of int days_between to get the minutes between those days.





                        /* ############################################################################
                         * ####     FINAL OUTPUT OF CALCULATING TIMES FROM CURRENT AND READY_AT     ###
                         * ############################################################################
                         */     
                     int current_TOTAL_MINUTES = current_HOUR * 60 + current_MINUTE;    // Multiply hour by 60 to get the minutes in the hour = RIGHT NOW'S time in minute format
                     int ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES = convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military * 60 + get_ready_at_MINUTE + minutes_difference_in_days_between;

                     PU_time_until_late = ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES - current_TOTAL_MINUTES;



                LOGCAT.DEBUG("READY_AT " + tracking_Number,"'" + days_between + "'" + " days between today and when the package is scheduled for pickup");

                LOGCAT.DEBUG("READY_AT " + tracking_Number, "ready_at String's time = "   + parse_ready_at_ARRAY +
                               "      Time now in Minutes = "      + current_TOTAL_MINUTES + 
                               "      ready_at time in Minutes = " + ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES +
                               "      Minutes left to complete pickup = " + PU_time_until_late + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + " ");




                }
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
                LOGCAT.DEBUG("Jobs", "Error Splitting/Converting ready_at Time");


        }                
        }







public void GetWindowParameters() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
    Jobs.this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    Jobs.this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.listviewbackground);

/*  params.x = 0;
    params.height = 480;
    params.width = 480;
    params.y = 160; */
    params.y = 160;
    params.height = 600;
    params.dimAmount = .70f;
    Jobs.this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
}
```

Heres the code to get the time difference **public void parse_ready_at()***WARNING* Im pretty sure there is a MUCH easier way to do this but, I'm new and dont know any better lol

```
    public void parse_ready_at(JSONObject JobsArray, int i1) {

                String parse_ready_at_ARRAY;
                String tracking_Number;         

        try {   for (i1 = 0; i1 < JOBS.length(); i1++) {
                    JobsArray = JOBS.getJSONObject(i1);

                    parse_ready_at_ARRAY = JobsArray.getString(ready_at);
                    tracking_Number = JobsArray.getString(job);


                //Example of ready_at String --> "ready_at": "07/25/2012 08:26:00 PM" we split time from date to get time only

    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"); // <--- Correct format to read "lastLatitudeUpdate"               
        try {   parserSDF.parse(parse_ready_at_ARRAY);      
                }


        catch   (ParseException e) {    LOGCAT.DEBUG("JOBS parse_ready_at", "Error parsing tracking number = " + tracking_Number + "      ready_at Array = " + parse_ready_at_ARRAY + " Error = " + e.toString());      } 



                    /* ################################################
                     * ####     DISSECTING READY_AT STRING ARRAY    ###
                     * ################################################
                     */
                String[] dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME = parse_ready_at_ARRAY.split(" ");       // Splitting space between 07/25/2012 and 08:26:00 and PM
                String   get_ready_at_DATE = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[0]);  // Set at 0 because we want date.  07-25-2012
                String   get_ready_at_TIME = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[1]);  // Set at 1 because we want time.  08:26:00
                String   get_ready_at_AMPM = String.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE_TIME[2]);   // Set at 2 because we want AM PM. 


                    /* ########################################################
                     * ####     GETTING DATE FROM READY_AT STRING ARRAY     ###
                     * ########################################################
                     */             
                String[]  dissect_ready_at_DATE = get_ready_at_DATE.split("/");              // Splitting the / between 07 and 25 and 2012 from 07/25/2012
                     int  get_ready_at_MONTH = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[0]);    // Set at 0 because we want month. 07
                     int  get_ready_at_DAY =   Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[1]);    // Set at 1 because we want day.   25
                     int  get_ready_at_YEAR =  Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_DATE[2]);    // Set at 2 because we want yeay.  2012



                    /* ########################################################
                     * ####     GETTING TIME FROM READY_AT STRING ARRAY     ###
                     * ########################################################
                     */                 
                String[]  dissect_ready_at_TIME = get_ready_at_TIME.split(":");              // Splitting the : between 08 and   26 and 00 
                     int  get_ready_at_HOUR = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_TIME[0]);     // Set at 0 because we want hour.   08
                     int  get_ready_at_MINUTE = Integer.valueOf(dissect_ready_at_TIME[1]);   // Set at 1 because we want minute. 26 




                    /* ################################################################
                     * ####     CONVERT HOUR FROM READY_AT STRING TO MILITARY TIME  ###
                     * ################################################################
                     */ 
                     int convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = 0;                              // By default, ready_at String is in 12 hour format. we need to fix it so it is military time.

                     if (get_ready_at_AMPM.contentEquals("PM")) {                            // Checking to see if ready_at String has a PM at the end
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = get_ready_at_HOUR + 12;         // If it does, add 12 so we can get military time           
                     }

                     if (get_ready_at_HOUR == 12 & get_ready_at_AMPM.contentEquals("PM")  ) {// If hour is set at 12 PM, leave it at 12
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = 12;
                     }

                     if (get_ready_at_AMPM.matches("AM"))  {                                 // Do Nothing if its AM
                         convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military = get_ready_at_HOUR + 0;
                     }





                    /* ############################################################
                     * ####     GET THE CURRENT DATE/TIME FROM USERS DEVICE     ###
                     * ############################################################
                     */     
                     int    current_MONTH =  Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);        // Get todays month
                     int    current_DAY =    Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // Get todays date
                     int    current_YEAR =   Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);         // Get todays year

                     int    current_HOUR =   Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  // Get todays Hour in military format
                     int    current_MINUTE = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);       // Get todays minute         



                     int current_year_FIXUP = current_YEAR - 1900;          // example, this year is 2013, subtract 1900 you get 113 which is what Date parameter is requesting
                     int get_ready_at_year_FIXUP = get_ready_at_YEAR - 1900;

                     int get_ready_at_MONTH_FIXUP =  // * We dont need to fixup current_MONTH because java has already done so
                             get_ready_at_MONTH - 1; // <-- we subtract 1 because according to parameters, January starts at 0 and December is 11 


                     /* 
                      *  How to use Date(int, int, int) 
                      * 
                      * 
                      *     *Parameters*
                      *         - year  the year, 0 is 1900. 
                      *         - month  the month, 0 - 11. 
                      *         - day  the day of the month, 1 - 31 
                      */

                     Date ready_at_time = new Date(get_ready_at_year_FIXUP, get_ready_at_MONTH_FIXUP, get_ready_at_DAY); // (2010, June, 20th) = (110, 5, 20) June is 5  instead of 6 because we start 
                     Date current_time = new Date(current_year_FIXUP, current_MONTH, current_DAY);                       // January at 0 in Java. As for days, it starts at 1 like normal.


                     int days_between = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(current_time), new DateTime(ready_at_time)).getDays();    // Get the difference in days of current date and ready_at date

                     int minutes_difference_in_days_between = days_between * 1440;  // 1440 minutes = 1 day. multiply with the date difference of int days_between to get the minutes between those days.





                        /* ############################################################################
                         * ####     FINAL OUTPUT OF CALCULATING TIMES FROM CURRENT AND READY_AT     ###
                         * ############################################################################
                         */     
                     int current_TOTAL_MINUTES = current_HOUR * 60 + current_MINUTE;    // Multiply hour by 60 to get the minutes in the hour = RIGHT NOW'S time in minute format
                     int ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES = convert_ready_at_HOUR_to_military * 60 + get_ready_at_MINUTE + minutes_difference_in_days_between;

                     PU_time_until_late = ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES - current_TOTAL_MINUTES;


                LOGCAT.DEBUG("READY_AT " + tracking_Number,"'" + days_between + "'" + " days between today and when the package is scheduled for pickup");

                LOGCAT.DEBUG("READY_AT " + tracking_Number, "ready_at String's time = "   + parse_ready_at_ARRAY +
                               "      Time now in Minutes = "      + current_TOTAL_MINUTES + 
                               "      ready_at time in Minutes = " + ready_at_TOTAL_MINUTES +
                               "      Minutes left to complete pickup = " + PU_time_until_late + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + " ");




                }
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
                LOGCAT.DEBUG("Jobs", "Error Splitting/Converting ready_at Time");
            }       


}
```

[image]

Basically I want those lights to resemble on-time, late etc... not looking to be fed with a golden spoon, just some guidance towards the right direction thats all. Thanks!

EDIT here is my stack trace I forgot to include. I am getting a null pointer exception in onPostExecute. I have declared the textView and already defined it in my onCreate. I believe I have already called it properly in my ListAdapter as well.

```
 if ( PU_ time_until_late < 60) { imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundColor (R.drawable.green_light);  }
```

EDIT Okay, I figured out why I was getting a null exception when calling imageViewReadyAt Textview. That textview belongs to another XML that belongs in the custom list_item. Still could use some help though.

Comment: If it is crashing you need to give us a stack trace. It also helps if you post the entire code instead of snippets since that can provide more context. Are you attempting to populate the listview directly from a HTTP response with json content ?

Comment: Ahh your right. Apologies, im not near a computer at the moment but i remember exactly rhe logcat error. Iwas getting a null pointer exception in on post execute of my asynctask by  If  ( PU_ time_until_late < 60) { imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundColor (R.drawable.green_light);}

Comment: Hey John, a full logcat would be helpful! Have you tried debugging the line that fails to find out exactly what is giving you the nullPointerException?

Comment: Why you are using i1 instead of just defining the variable as i?

Comment: @JohnNguyen can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or what, but I've also had issues modifying the UI from `onPostExecute()`. To work around it I'll either call a method from there to the main activity and have that work with views, or use a handler and post a message to the proper activity that is using the UI thread.

To make sure I'm on the UI thread I usually use a handler message instead like so:

```
Handler handlerJobs = new jobsHandler();

public class jobsHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.arg1) {
            case 1:
                updateBackgroundColor(msg.arg2);
                break;

            default:
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}

private void updateBackgroundColor(int dataPassedInMessage) {
    if  (JOB != null) {
        assigned.setText("");
    } else {
        assigned.setText("You have no jobs assigned");
    }

    GetWindowParameters();

        /** Updating parsed JSON data into ListView */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Jobs.this, contactList, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { job, pays, ready_at, due_by, new_job, PU_late, DEL_late}, 
                                   new int[] { R.id.job1, R.id.pays1, R.id.ready_at1, R.id.due_by1, R.id.newjob1, R.id.imageViewReadyAt, R.id.imageViewDueBy });


    TextView imageViewReadyAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewReadyAt);
    //Change color/answer/etc for textView_5

    if ( PU_time_until_late > 60) {
        // if more than 60 minutes
        imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification);
    }

    if ( PU_time_until_late < 60) {
        //if less than 60
        imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_light);
    }

    if ( PU_time_until_late < 30) {
        // if less than 30
        imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_light);
    }

    if ( PU_time_until_late < 1) {
        // if less than 1 minutes
        imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_light);
    }

    setListAdapter(adapter);        

    pDialog.dismissProgressDialog(Jobs.this);

    }
}
```

And then to call it you would use:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Message updateBackground = new Message();
    updateBackground.arg1 = 1;
    updateBackground.arg2 = R.drawable.green_light;  //or any int you need to pass
    handlerJobs.sendMessage(updateBackground);
}
```

edit: updated the example so it should work with your code

Comment: THank you Jon, I will give your suggestion a try tomorrow and reply back to you with results. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Jon, so far its looking good! I just barely started messing with it and Im trying to expand on what you suggested right now. I'll get back to you shortly!

Comment: I'm having a hard time implementing your suggestion just because I don't understand exactly what the code is executing. Could you please tell me what is going on with message.arg1 and arg2?

Comment: Sure, the `Message` object is basically just a container that can be used to pass information to a `Handler`. It has three different `int` that can be used to send simple basic information(arg1, arg2, what), or you can also include a `Bundle` with the `Message.setData()` method. [Message | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html)

Comment: Overriding `handleMessage()` in the `Handler` will let it intercept the `Message` from the `Looper` so you can see what needs to be done. But, again, you may be able to just create a new method and call that from onPostExecute() since it's all in the same activity. Sometimes the handler is overkill, but so far I've found it to be the most reliable way to update the UI if you're getting NPEs.

Comment: it seems like it is only willing to update one row in my listview. I believe its perhaps due to im using a simpleadapter, or the textView imageViewReadyAt, is not located in the XML from my onCreate. imageViewReadyAt is actually located from the XML of the simpleadapter. Ill try to mess with it some more and report back shortly. thanks Jon!

Comment: You can use the view your onItemClickListener listener passes. I would need to experiment with it before I'm able to give an example or anything, but it shouldn't be too much trouble to pass a soft reference or it's index to your new activity. An index you could pass through the Handler, but having the actual view would let you use `View.post()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are setting background color instead of setting background image. Your image setting code should be as follows e.g. :

```
imageViewReadyAt.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.green_light);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply hrehman. I've actually tried that way, but it gave me an error. I was testing setBackgroundColor and it actually does what I need it to do.

Comment: Can you post full log trace here.